Looking for Urban Fantasy Novel Taking Place In NYC Written in Past 10-years
Female lead, addicted to coke, works with New York Police, serial murders.
She's called to a murder that has been "cloaked" in the NY subway system. When exposed, it seems posed as if a piece of art. She takes her observations to a police sketch artist with an MFA who helps identify that art aspect.
It FEELS like an R. J. Blain book, but I've gone through my collection and can't find it under any of her pen names.
I've also tried various search engines and keyword and have come up with nada!
Please help, it's driving me nuts and adding to my concerns about senioritis!
DavidW, NJohnny:
What are the elements that make this a fantasy? –
The cloaking of the murder scene is magical in origin as well as part of the murder itself.
There are other victims that point to an artist that is magically murdering and posing the victims as art.

I'm becoming convinced I dreamt the whole story! I have done a content scan of my library for keywords. Nothing. I've checked books I got from Amazon. Nothing.
I swear I remember the whole section of the book:
A murder is staged in a NYC subway. It's cloaked by magic until rush hour. The protagonist (a female that live on Coca Cola) is called in with her male partner. She goes into some state to "view" the body that has been elaborately staged. And she realizes that it was "stage" like a piece of art.
They go back to HQ (either NYPD or FBI) and call in a sketch artist with an MFA. She describes what she saw, he draws it, and agrees that it is art.
After looking at other murders she determines that there were other cases that fit this pattern and they are dealing with a serial killer.
Anyone have any ideas? Please!

What are the elements that make this a fantasy?

Can you clarify what you mean by the murder being "cloaked"? I have a feeling that's the part that makes it sci-fi or fantasy but it's not very clear what you mean by it.

Yes, needs more amplifying info as to why this is either Sci-Fi/Fantasy/horror.

The "cloaking" is magical in nature so that the murder scene does not appear until the perpetrator wants it to. Also there is a magical element to the murders themselves. Also the solutions have the same approach.

Can you edit those details into the question?

F1Krazy
I've edited the question to reflect more detail:
The "cloaking" is magical in nature so that the murder scene does not appear until the perpetrator wants it to. Also there is a magical element to the murders themselves. Also the solutions have the same approach.

Definitely sounds on-topic now, and it also sounds tantalizingly familiar, at least the aspect of the villain having arranged things so that the murder is suddenly revealed. Unfortunately, I've had no luck with my search so far.

After taking a pause I went back and re-indexed and search my Calibre library. I found it! (I'm not nuts!).
Bad Witch: A Cat McKenzie Novel #2 by Lauren Dawes!
Yay ME!
